# Review the result of git-merge before the actual merge

Tags: git

Is there a way to review the result of a merge between two branches before actually merging them ?

When attempting to merge branch A to branch B, I usually checkout a temporary branch from B, merge it with branch A, then I'd create a diff patch, or just checkout to that temporary branch and check whether everything is working fine before merging A to B.

Does git provide a command or a feature that would accomplishes this?

Comment: `git merge --no-commit`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As Marian Theisen suggested, you can do this to do the merge without committing

```
git merge --no-commit <branchname>
```

You can back out of that merge with

```
git reset --hard
```

Also, remember that it is always easy to change your mind and return to a previous state in Git. You can do a full merge, including commit, inspect the complete result and if you change your mind you can

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

to throw away the merge and be back at the commit before the merge.

In fact, at any point during the merge resolution, you can do

```
git reset --merge
```

To abort the merge and throw away just the merge changes.

Answer (score 24):

I call this the "code review workflow" and do it all the time.

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff branchname
```

Without the `--no-ff` flag, if Git can do a fast-forward then it will do that. (As expected, as in the case of a fast forward, there's no merge commit to create.)

I have this alias setup in `.gitconfig` for convenience:

```
rev = merge --no-ff --no-commit
```

So that I can simply do:

```
git rev branchname
```

The idea is that all features are developed in separate branches, and each feature is reviewed and merged by somebody other than the author. As other answers pointed out you can abort the merge with:

```
git reset --merge
```

and ask the author to make more changes.

To view the log with only the merge commits I use this other alias:

```
revlog = log --first-parent
```

This way the log becomes a timeline of the large steps: feature by feature rather than commit by commit.

Comment: There is no risk in a fast forward merge. Fast forward merges are the best: no risk, no polution, just move the branch-pointer forward. Why anybody would so casually use that --no-ff flag is a mystery to me. If anybody can shed any light on this, please do so. From my own experience I would warn people to really understand what fast-forwarding means before deciding against it.

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen I agree with your sentiment. But this is not a case of "casually using the `--no-ff` flag". This is an answer to the specific question of reviewing changes before merging. Although fast-forward is not a merge, using the `--no-ff` seems to match the intention of the OP.

Comment: I found this was a good way for me to merge a develop branch into master, but reset just the env/settings file back to normal before the merge got committed. However I am sure there is a better solution than me doing this to maintain different environment settings.

Comment: In my case, I had to review and cherrypick each and every change manually before merging, so to make the process easier, I did `git reset` to unstage all the modified files as well.

Answer (score 5):

Why take the trouble? Just do the merge, test it, and if you don't like it, then `git reset --hard HEAD^` to move back to pre-merge state. Doing some temporary or half-way merge just increases your work whether you decide you want to keep the merge or not.

Comment: Reviewing a merge provides the reviewer to correct issues in the code prior to a merge, and allows the developer of the source branch to fix the code before merging. Remember also that sometimes code changes require additional operational steps, for example database migrations. for that reason the just-merge-and-test is not always the best.

Comment: @crafter Except that you can merge locally and test, before opening a PR. This results in full-testing of the final state before merging into master is actually accepted.